# Not able to reuse WebClient after initial use? Tried resetting headers, didn't work

Tags: c#, webclient

I have this code:

```
Console.WriteLine(strURL);
WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
myWebClient.Headers["Content-Type"] = "image/png";
myWebClient.DownloadFile(new Uri(strURL), "test_image.jpeg");
myWebClient.Dispose();
```

I have to reuse this webclient to download multiple images. This works for ONE image but fails for all starting from the next one, throwing a System.Net WebException, with additional information stating that an exeption occured during a webclient request.

I've tried resetting headers (as was stated in many questions like this). What could be the issue?

Comment: Perhaps try not disposing it?

Comment: Please add more exception details...

Comment: If you want to reuse it then don't dispose it.

Comment: Okay, I changed the name of the image file, and it seems to be fine. Could this explain any issues? But shouldn't it overwrite the image each time?

Comment: Try downloading 2nd one first.  There may be a cookie that needs to be deleted.   Some server don't allow two connections from same client.  The server may not immediately recognize the 1st connection being disposed.  You may want to use fiddler to help find root cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about delete the file first before overwrite it ?

```
Console.WriteLine(strURL);
using (WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient())
{
  myWebClient.Headers["Content-Type"] = "image/png";
  if (File.Exists("test_image.jpeg"))
  {
    File.Delete("test_image.jpeg");
  }
  myWebClient.DownloadFile(new Uri(strURL), "test_image.jpeg");
}
```

Comment: I just tried this, and I got this error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll. Additional information: Parameter is not valid.
The Debugger highlights this line: `Application.Run(new Form1());`

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out eventually. I had to clear a bunch of instances of that image being used.

Comment: "DownloadFile" has nothing to do with "Drawing.dll". You must search it in your form. Probably during set your picture in pictureBox, or similar.